# Error in case of nested for loops

Tags: forloop, relatedto

I have a comment section with comments and subcomments. A comment relates directly to the blog post while a subcomment relates to a comment.

Now, I have the following problem on the entry page: Showing the comments only is not a problem:

```
{% for comment in craft.entries({
    section: comments,
    relatedTo: { targetElement: entry, field: "relentry" },
    order:     "sortOrder",
    limit:     null
}) %}
    <p>X</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I insert the subcomments, I get the error message `Unexpected "}"`:

```
{% for comment in craft.entries({
    section: comments,
    relatedTo: { targetElement: entry, field: "relentry" },
    order:     "sortOrder",
    limit:     null
}) %}
    <p>X</p>
    {% for subcomment in craft.entries({
        section: comments,
        relatedTo: { targetElement: comment, field: "relentry" },
        order:     "sortOrder",
        limit:     null
    }) %}
        <p>Y</p>
    {% endfor % }
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably your second-from-last line:

```
{% endfor % }
```

should be:

```
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Of course, you're right. Thank you very much!